# Shell Output Alignment

Tags: shell, awk, sed

How to align this script output.

```
for instance in `find /bxp/*/*/*/prod/*/apache_*/httpd/htdocs/ -type f -name status.txt` ; do
 echo "`hostname`: `ls -ltr |  ${instance}` : `cat ${instance}`"
done
```

Output looks like:

```
r008abc, /bxp/xip/xip.pentaho-server_pentaho-server-assembly/pentaho.prod.jobengine/prod/xip.pentaho-server_web.partition_0.0.1/apache_5.3.3-2.2.
26/httpd/htdocs/status.txt, Web server is disabled
```

However i want the output be like:

```
r008abc| xip - xip.pentaho-server_web.partition_0.0.1 | Web server is disabled
```

xip - is nothing but the second column of the $instance - xip.pentaho-server_web.partition_0.0.1 is 6th column of the $instance. How can I achieve this. I tried awk command but it was not helpful. Your suggestion is appreciated.

Command I tried

```
for instance in `find /bxp/*/*/*/prod/*/apache_*/httpd/htdocs/ -type f -name status.txt` ; do
 echo "`hostname`: `"ls -ltr | awk -F '/' '{print $3}"' ${instance}` : `cat ${instance}`"
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this oneliner:

```
find /bxp/*/*/*/prod/*/apache_*/httpd/htdocs/ -type f -name status.txt | awk -F/ -v host=$(hostname) '{cmd="cat \047" $0 "\047"; if ((cmd | getline out) > 0){printf "%s| %s - %s | %s\n", host,$3, $7, out} close(cmd);}'
```

Explanation of awk-script:

```
awk -F/                                           # use / as field separator
    -v host=$(hostname)                           # set var host      
'{
   cmd="cat \047" $0 "\047"                       # define cmd 
   if ((cmd | getline out) > 0)                   # read output of cmd
      printf "%s| %s - %s | %s\n",host,$3,$7,out; # print formatted result
   close(cmd);
 }'
```

Comment: This is just Awesome..Thanks. i was breaking head for this for hours.

Comment: Changed output to the appropriate columns.

Comment: I don't understand what is being asked for in the question but wrt the above awk script: that will fail given various input values. Always quote your shell variables: `cmd="cat \047" $0 "\047"` and test for getline success/failure before using it's result or you'll be silently printing the last successfully read value if/when a failure occurs. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Comment: That's enlightenment. +1.